# Interface Builder Views not showing up

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift, interface-builder

All of my view controllers suddenly had this bug.  Nothing shows up in interface builder, but it works fine when I run it.  This makes it so I can't edit my views in interface builder.  Whats going on here?  Xcode 6.1 GM ios 8.1 B1.  Swift.[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume you made your design in a size class other than wAny / hAny. Switch back to the size class you used for design and your controls will reappear.

Comment: This worked for me when I had the same problem. Zisoft, do you know why this is?

Comment: Controls designed in wAny/hAny are available in all other size classes. Make all your desing in wAny/hAny and only the differences to that in the other size classes.

Comment: What does this mean? This seems likely to be the answer, but where do I look to find or change what my size class is? Is it a ViewController property?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you press Command+Delete, meant for removing objects from only certain size classes. If you just did it, you can undo it, but otherwise I looked around and I can't find a way to turn them back on. The only menu references to it are after you press Command+Delete to "Undo Turn Off", so it may be a bug right now unless theres an alternative way to turn the layers back on.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Harrison is correct, the greyed out views on the left mean they have been deleted for a certain size class, try changing the size class and see if they are active in a different size class

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help.  I had designed the views in regular regular  and then changed it to any any unknowingly.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered similar problems.And I solve this problem by check install...

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This because of size classes. May be you uninstall some constraints in wAny and hAny. You need to re-install these constraints. After that you are able to see your view again.